# How to configure Quarkus Dev Services besides prod config?

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

I want to use dev services to start postgres db on local application startup (quarkus profile = local).
Dev services are active in test and dev mode, so by not defining `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` it is actually working already with following config:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres
```

However, I don't know how to configure this besides a prod configuration which has a `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` defined e.g.

```
%local.quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=true
%local.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
%local.quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
%local.quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
%local.quarkus.datasource.password=postgres

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://myProdDB.com:5432/mydb
```

If I start the application with quarkus profile = local, instead of spinning up postgres on docker, quarkus falls back to the prod property `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` which I don't want for my local dev environment.

If I prefix the prod properties with a prod profile like `%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` this fallback can be prevented, however, I want to follow the convention that prod properties are default, thus not prefixed with profile.

I already tried without success to somehow set `%local.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` to an empty value to prevent fallback to `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url`:

`%local.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=""` ->  `java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: ""`

`%local.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=null` -> `java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: null`

`%local.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=` -> `io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit default but configured datasource default not found: the default EntityManagerFactory will not be created. To solve this, configure the default datasource. Refer to https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource for guidance.`

Comment: Have you tried changing `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://myProdDB.com:5432/mydb` to `%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://myProdDB.com:5432/mydb`?

Comment: Yes (as mentioned `If I prefix the prod properties with a prod profile like %prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url this fallback can be prevented`).
However, I want prod properties to be default, thus not prefixed with profile.